# How does Google App engines cold boot deal with global variables?

Tags: google-app-engine

My python API initializes a global variable which takes about 10 seconds to fully initialize before the server starts running. I'm wondering if when GAE initializes a new instance, this same initialization is required? or am I able to access the same variable across multiple instances?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd need to initialise per-instance, unless you can put it in memcache.

Comment: i've read that memcache isn't guaranteed to persist. But in the above case, would it take the cold boot time + 10 seconds to start up a new instance then?

Comment: Yes, cold boot time + initialisation time unless you can somehow cache the global in a globally available store such as memcache - no guaranteed as you observe - or datastore/database etc.

Comment: Not sure if it's your case, but if you're using thread safe configuration, it may happen that each thread tries to instantiate the global variables causing blocking contention across threads, if that's the case, you can apply lazy instantiation as explained in this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/app-engine-startup-time-and-the-global-variable-problem-7ab10de1f349).

Comment: @dhauptman yeah, I looked into that, unfortunately, the global vars in my case is used in pretty much every one of my endpoints.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is just complementary to the other mentioned approaches, in most if not all cases they can be combined.

If you're in the standard environment you can take advantage of the [warmup requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/configuring-warmup-requests) to well... warm (most of) your instances up before real traffic hits them.

Multithreading complexity doesn't really matter in such cases since you **know** that no other request can hit the instance until its init isn't complete - i.e. until it successfully responds to the warmup request. So you can optimize for this case while still playing it safe (even if not very efficient) for the rare cases when instances still start up cold and can get multiple requests in parallel.

Warmup requests [aren't supported](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/upgrading#warmup_requests) in the flexible environment, but:

> To warm up your app, implement a [health check handler](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/reference/app-yaml#updated_health_checks) that only
>   returns a [ready status](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#readiness_checks) when the application is warmed up.
>
> For example, you can create a readiness check that returns a ready
>   status after initializing the cache so your app won't receive traffic
>   until it is ready.

Answer (score 2):

Each instance in the application is a separate interpreter, so globals need to be initialised per instance.

If initialisation is costly, but the computed value doesn't change frequently it may be worth storing the value in memcache, the datastore, a database or some other globally available store.  Retrieval from memcache is fast, but persistence is not guaranteed, so you may need to re-run the initialisation from time to time.  Retrieval from the datastore or a database is usually slower, but persistence is guaranteed in normal circumstances.

As dhauptman observes in the comments, [this article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/app-engine-startup-time-and-the-global-variable-problem-7ab10de1f349) contains some advice on lazy-loading global variables.